# Drupal site - adding canonical rel in htaccess for https to http

Tags: http, drupal, https, canonical-link, indexed

Recently, I have signup for Cloudflare. My website is get new https option. After a few days Google is indexed my pages with https and http and now I have duplicate content. I don't need https for my website so I have switched off this option on Cloudflare, but I still have indexed pages with https. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the solution but i think if you change your $base_url variable in /sites/default/settings.php.

It will always open what you want (https or http), define your URL as http://www.mywebsite.com. As per google index is concern it will be updated when you website is accessed frequently with new URL.